# Why this part of code never works in Yii?

Tags: php, yii2

I have this code in my controller:

```
public function actionEdit()
{
    $model = new Section();
    $id = ($_GET['id']);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $record = Menu::findOne(['id' => $id]);
        $record->name = $model->name;
        $record->save();
        return $this->redirect(['menu/index']);
    }
    if ($model = Menu::findOne(['id' => $id]))
    {
        return $this->render('edit', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }
}
```

this part of code have never worked:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
    {
        $record = Menu::findOne(['id' => $id]);
        $record->name = $model->name;
        $record->save();
        return $this->redirect(['menu/index']);
    }
```

if it needs, that's my view file:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Алексей
 * Date: 14.01.2016
 * Time: 19:00
 */
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
?>
<div class="menu-form">
    <? echo $message?>
    <? $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <div class="hidden">
        <?

            echo $form->field($model, 'id');
        ?>
    </div>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>
    <?= Html::submitButton('Изменить название', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: it means don't run ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your code looks a little messy and that's probably what's causing the issue. By the way, you can always use the [Gii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-gii-index.html)'s CRUD Generator and compare the structure of your actions.

About your code: The `$id` parameter is required for this action, since you can't edit something without the id. So you should call it with your function: `public function actionEdit($id)`.

I notice you have 2 models being called in your action. Not sure why are you using this `Section` (it's never being saved), but i think you want to create a new `Section` everytime someone edit a `Menu`, populate the `Menu` with that information and getting rid of `Section` (again, so far there is no point of this `Section` model). For that, you will need to add a second parameter in your [load method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#load()-detail). Here is a example:

```
public function actionEdit($id)
{
    $sectionModel = new Section();

    if ($menuModel = Menu::findOne($id)) {
        if ($sectionModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), 'Menu')) {
            $menuModel->name = $sectionModel->name;
            $menuModel->save();

            return $this->redirect(['menu/index']);
        }

        return $this->render('edit', [
            'model' => $menuModel 
        ]);
    }
}
```

If that's not it, can you please explain better what are you trying to accomplish?